# Why do I keep getting false for some() javascript array method for an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
const menu = [{
    name: "tofu fritters",
    ingredients: ["tofu", "egg yolk", "breadbrumbs", "paprika"],
  },
  {
    name: "black bean curry",
    ingredients: ["black beans", "garam masala", "rice"],
  },
  {
    name: "chocolate tiffin",
    ingredients: [
      "dark chocolate",
      "egg",
      "flour",
      "brown sugar",
      "vanilla essence",
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "hummus",
    ingredients: ["chickpeas", "tahini", "lemon", "garlic", "salt"],
  },
];

searchResult = menu.some(menuItem => menuItem.ingredients === 'flour');
console.log(searchResult);
```

I was expecting this to return true since flour is present in the array for the third menu item but it returns false.  Some() only seems to return true if I remove the array entirely from the object.

Comment: your ingredients _contain_ flour. This is not the same as your ingredients _being_ flour.

Comment: thanks!  it now works if I use menuItem.ingredients.includes('flour')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `menuItem.ingredients` is an array, try with `menuItem.ingredients.includes('flour')` instead of `menuItem.ingredients === 'flour'`

> The [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
const menu = [{
    name: "tofu fritters",
    ingredients: ["tofu", "egg yolk", "breadbrumbs", "paprika"],
  },
  {
    name: "black bean curry",
    ingredients: ["black beans", "garam masala", "rice"],
  },
  {
    name: "chocolate tiffin",
    ingredients: [
      "dark chocolate",
      "egg",
      "flour",
      "brown sugar",
      "vanilla essence",
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "hummus",
    ingredients: ["chickpeas", "tahini", "lemon", "garlic", "salt"],
  },
];

searchResult = menu.some(menuItem => menuItem.ingredients.includes('flour'));
console.log(searchResult);
```

Answer (score -1):

`menuItem` is an Object `menuItem.ingredients` is an array do we can not directly equalize to a variable, but we can check if it contains the variable so `menuItem.ingredients.includes('flour')` work for this

```js
const menu = [{
    name: "tofu fritters",
    ingredients: ["tofu", "egg yolk", "breadbrumbs", "paprika"],
  },
  {
    name: "black bean curry",
    ingredients: ["black beans", "garam masala", "rice"],
  },
  {
    name: "chocolate tiffin",
    ingredients: [
      "dark chocolate",
      "egg",
      "flour",
      "brown sugar",
      "vanilla essence",
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "hummus",
    ingredients: ["chickpeas", "tahini", "lemon", "garlic", "salt"],
  },
];

searchResult = menu.some(menuItem => menuItem.ingredients.includes('flour') );
console.log(searchResult);
```